# Where can I find the relevant ARM documentation?

Tags: software-development, hardware

Could someone provide links to the correct documentation on the ARM site that relates to the processor in the Raspberry Pi?

It would be useful to have a canonical answer for which ARM docs to use and where they can be found. I've registerd on the ARM website, so I can download them, but I need to know which ones!

Comment: @Jivings - I have looked, it's not obvious for a beginner like myself which docs are the correct ones,  ARM11 uses the ARM6 instruction set which has been superseded by the ARM7 A&R, I did try and make it community wiki, I'm not sure if that exists any more?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The FAQ states the CPU is an ARM1176JZF-S which is an ARM11 Classic processor the processor details are available [here](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/classic/arm11/arm1176.php) on the ARM website.

The Technical Reference Manual is available via the [ARM documentation centre](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp)

Select:  **ARM11 Processors** -> **ARM1176** -> **RM1176JZF-S Technical Reference Manual**
(Or as a PDF from [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0333h/DDI0333H_arm1176jzs_r0p7_trm.pdf))

The **ARM Architecture Reference Manual** that covers the ARM11 instruction set is the
"ARM Architecture Reference Manual ARMv7-A and ARMv7-R edition":

> This manual describes the instruction set, memory model, and programmers' model for ARMv7 (A&R profile) compliant processors, including:
>   Cortex-A series
>   Cortex-R series
>   Qualcomm Scorpion.
>   It also describes the later ARMv6 architecture releases for ARM11 processors, and describes Thumb-2 and the TrustZone security extensions.

It can be downloaded from the ARM website [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0406-/) (registration is required).